# How does multer determine the value of file.mimetype

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

[Multer's](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) `file` object contains a `mimetype` value. The documentation describes it as "Mime type of the file", but provides no other details.

How is the value of this field determined? Is it simply the `Content-Type:` provided by the client (which can easily be spoofed) or is the uploaded file evaluated in some way that can help determine the true file type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By tracking the source code, it's come from `content-type` header.

Here is how I track:

[make-middleware.js in Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/lib/make-middleware.js): Where there is a `busboy` stream object listening on `file` event and having `mimetype` as one of the input parameter of callback function. The `mimetype` is appended to `req.files` that the user got.

[busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/blob/master/lib/main.js): The `busboy` instance is created with request headers parsed by it's own `parseHeaders` and `parseParams` function. You can find it's doing something on `content-type` header.

Further tracking, you will find it [applies the Dicer object](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/blob/master/lib/types/multipart.js) to listen on `headers` event and emit `file` event to `busboy` with parsed mimeType.